# Getting TypeError : h.has is not a function error

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to test backbone.js , however, I am getting `TypeError : h.has is not a function` error. My HTML Code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Theater</h1>
    <div id="mainContainer"></div>
   <input type="text" value="Enter HashTag" id="hashtag" />
     <script type="text/template" id="tmplt-Tweets">
            <ul>
            </ul>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="tmplt-Tweet">
            <div>*******************************************************</div>
            <div><%= url %> </div>
            <div><%= text %> </div>
            <div><%= html %> </div>
            <div><%= date %> </div>
            <div><%= id %> </div>
            <div><%= img %> </div>
            <div><%= name %> </div>
            <div><%= rt %> </div>
    </script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/underscore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/libs/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

BackBone code:

```
/// <reference path="../../scripts/libs/jquery-1.7.1.js" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/libs/underscore.js" />
/// <reference path="../../scripts/libs/backbone-min.js" />
var Tweet = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates:{}
}
Tweet.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({})
Tweet.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Tweet.Models.Movie,
    initialize: function(){
        console.log("No Tweets Yet")
    }
});
 Tweet.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Tweets").html())
Tweet.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#mainContainer"),
    template: Tweet.Templates.movies,
    //collection: new Theater.Collections.Movies(), //Not needed
    initialize: function () {
        //_.bindAll(this, "render", "addOne", "addAll");
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
        this.collection.bind("add", this.addOne, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        console.log("render")
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        $(this.el).html(this.template());
        this.addAll();
    },
    addAll: function () {
        console.log("addAll")
        this.collection.each(this.addOne);
    },
    addOne: function (model) {
        console.log("addOne")
        view = new Tweet.Views.Movie({ model: model });
        $("ul", this.el).append(view.render());
    }
})
 Tweet.Templates.movie = _.template($("#tmplt-Tweet").html())
Tweet.Views.Movie = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: "li",
    template: Tweet.Templates.movie,
    //events: { "click .delete": "test" },
    initialize: function () {
        //_.bindAll(this, 'render', 'test');
        this.model.bind('destroy', this.destroyItem, this);
        this.model.bind('remove', this.removeItem, this);
    },
    render: function () {
        return $(this.el).append(this.template(this.model.toJSON())) ;
    },
    removeItem: function (model) {
        console.log("Remove - " + model.get("Name"))
        this.remove();
    }
})
Tweet.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "http://localhost/assignment/index.php"  //http://localhost:22257/Theater/theater.htm
    },
    defaultRoute: function () {
        console.log("defaultRoute");
        Tweet.movies = new Tweet.Collections.Movies()
        new Tweet.Views.Movies({ collection: Tweet.movies }); //Add this line
        Tweet.movies.fetch();
        console.log(Tweet.movies.length)
    }
})
var appRouter = new Tweet.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

Any idea? Thanks

Comment: moved to 1.10 jquery, still the same error

Comment: Use the non-minified version of backbone.js instead of the minified version. Don't use any minified scripts when debugging. By using the full non-minified version you will have an easier time with error messages and stack traces.

Comment: Open the Chrome DevTools, select the Sources tab, and click the stop-sign-with-a-pause-button-inside-it icon in the lower left to set it to pause on all exceptions. Then it will stop when the error happens and you can look at the stack trace and variables to see what happened.

Comment: now getting TypeError: callBack is undefined

Answer (score 4):

You probably are using an outdated version of underscore library, please update it to fix the issue.
Also update to latest version of backbone.js if you still face any other issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved it by rearranging the order of js files to load in script tag. Make sure that jquery.js file is loaded before backbone.js file. This has resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that this issue is most likely caused by some libraries (backbone, underscore or jQuery) being out of date. To resolve please update to the latest, the below worked for me..

```
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.3.3/underscore-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/0.9.2/backbone-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```